# RequireJS import documentation

Tags: requirejs, webstorm, jsdoc

Im using in WebStorm editor. My project is using RequireJS with AMD. There is an example of code:

**dep.js**

```
define([], function () {
var exports = {
  helloWorld: function() { 
    console.log("Hello world");
  }
};
return exports;
});
```

**primary.js**

```
define(['dep'], function (dep) {
var exports = {
  sayHello: function() {
      dep.helloWorld();
  }
};
return exports;
});
```

How to document properly exports (this mainly described in other answers) and (important!) imports of such AMD modules, so WebStorm can have proper type hints on imported deps (like a "dep" variable in this example).

Answer (score 0):

According to [AMD howto](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html), it should be smth like

```
/**
 * @module dep
 */
define([], function() {
    /**
     * @constructor
     * @alias module:dep
     */
    var exports = {
        helloWorld: function() {
            console.log("Hello world");
        }
    };
    return exports;
});
```

Comment: I mostly interested in Import comments. Export comments are well explained in other questions, but they dont help WebStorm to see correct types for imported modules.