# GlimmerJS: how to use Glimmer as a lib (e.g. AMD) without building with ember-cli/broccoli

Tags: javascript, glimmer.js

[GlimmerJS](https://glimmerjs.com/) provides a bunch of npm packages (actually 20 packages are installed for simple demo in official tutorial https://glimmerjs.com/guides/). Every package contains in `dist/` folder several variants of scripts in the following subfolder:

- amd
- commonjs
- modules
- types

It makes me think that I can use Glimmer as AMD lib without its application-pipeline building stuff. 
I'm not againt using ember-cli/broccoli or building/packaging in general I'm just trying to take a smallest possible step to adopt Glimmer in an existing app and I don't want to introduce all its building pipeline magic.

So my question is how to create and render a Glimmer component in runtime having its template as string.

P.S. the key point is not using Glimmer as AMD but using it without building.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TypeScript playground to transpile, then use the transpiled exports of Glimmer as the boilerplate of an application. For example:

```js
document.body.innerText += require;

requirejs.config({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js"
    });
    
require([''],foo);


function foo(){
return define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.default = {
        types: {
            application: { definitiveCollection: 'main' },
            component: { definitiveCollection: 'components' },
            helper: { definitiveCollection: 'components' },
            renderer: { definitiveCollection: 'main' },
            template: { definitiveCollection: 'components' },
            util: { definitiveCollection: 'utils' },
            'component-manager': { definitiveCollection: 'component-managers' }
        },
        collections: {
            main: {
                types: ['application', 'renderer']
            },
            components: {
                group: 'ui',
                types: ['component', 'template', 'helper'],
                defaultType: 'component'
            },
            'component-managers': {
                types: ['component-manager']
            },
            utils: {
                unresolvable: true
            }
        }
    };
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js"></script>
```

**References**

- [RequireJS as an external dependency: jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/73xVu/)
- [Glimmer Resolver Configuration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glimmerjs/glimmer.js/master/packages/%40glimmer/application-test-helpers/src/default-resolver-configuration.ts)
- [glimmerjs/glimmer-resolver](https://github.com/glimmerjs/glimmer-resolver)
- [using jquery plugin in backbone with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567673/using-jquery-plugin-in-backbone-with-requirejs)
- [RequireJS import documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232208/requirejs-import-documentation)
- [Playground · TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)
- [Building your own API Playground – Contosio Labs](https://contos.io/building-your-own-api-playground-e1a9a1eb0180)